# reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script in an ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Following code run fine in a non-ajax environment.

```
<div id="target">
  <script>
      var thisScript1 = $('script').filter(':last');
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript1.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'target'
      });
  </script>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <script>
      var thisScript2 = $('script').filter(':last');
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript2.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'second'
      });
  </script>
</div>​
```

If I then reload the div 'target' with the same content using Ajax, `$('script').filter(':last')` references the last script of the page and not the current one anymore.

```
<div id="target"> // reloaded using Ajax
  <script>
      var thisScript1 = $('script').filter(':last');
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript1.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'second'
      });
  </script>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <script>
      var thisScript2 = $('script').filter(':last');
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript2.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'second'
      });
  </script>
</div>​
```

It's like *the current script is inserted where the old one was* (I'm guessing) though is correctly executed on load time.

How could I have the requested behavior on an Ajax environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i think is happening. When you're not performing an ajax request, this script runs first

```
<div id="target">
  <script>
      var thisScript1 = $('script').filter(':last');
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript1.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'target'
      });
</script>
```

And at the time this line is executed `var thisScript1 = $('script').filter(':last');` the only script is the script in the div `target` hence the selector picks it up. But when performing an ajax request, the content is reloaded.

```
<div id="target"> // reloaded using Ajax
  <script>
      var thisScript1 = $('script').filter(':last');
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript1.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'second'
      });
  </script>
</div>
```

So when this line is executed `var thisScript1 = $('script').filter(':last');` there's more than one script in the document. Hence you really need to select the first script here and not the last one.

You should use the `:first` to select the first script and `:last` to get the second script. So changing it around should work in both environments.

```
<div id="target">
  <script>
      var thisScript1 = $('script').filter(':first'); 
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript1.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'target'
      });
  </script>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <script>
      var thisScript2 = $('script').filter(':last');
      $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log(thisScript2.closest('div').attr('id')); // prints 'second'
      });
  </script>
</div>​
```

Or like frederic suggested, give them id's to uniquely identify them, then use those id's to select those scripts.

Comment: My page is dynamically built and number of scripts and location can not be predicted

Comment: But don't you know the id of the div that they will be in ?

Comment: Not really as the content can be imported in few different container